# Send multiple images API flutter

Tags: json, flutter

```
Future<void> updateImage(http.MultipartRequest request) async {
    var streamedResponse, response;
    bool Error = false;
    try {
      streamedResponse = await request.send();
      response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    } catch (err) {
      Error = true;
      continuosly = false;
      ErrorMessageDialog(context, err.toString(), () {});
    }
    if (!Error) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        WebAPIResponse Status =
            WebAPIResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        if (Status.Status == '0') {
          continuosly = true;
        } else {
          continuosly = false;
          ErrorMessageDialog(context, Status.ErrorMsg, () {});
        }
      } else {
        continuosly = false;
        ErrorMessageDialog(context, "Lỗi kết nối!", () {});
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> selectImageFromDevice() async {
    final List<XFile> listImageSelected =
        await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 40);
    if (listImageSelected.isEmpty) {
      return;
    } else {
      var postUri = Uri.parse(
          "//my_sever");
      var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", postUri);
      Map<String, String> header = {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      };

      request.fields['ID'] = widget.ct.ID;
      for (var i in listImageSelected) {
        originalImage = File(i.path);
        //nén ảnh
        Uint8List? compressedImage =
            await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(originalImage!.path,
                quality: 40);
        String fileName = i.name;

        request.fields['FileName'] = fileName;
        request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('FileContent', compressedImage!,
              filename: fileName),
        );
        request.headers.addAll(header);
        updateImage(request);
      }
    }
  }
```

Here the code. How can I post multiple images of Uint8List at one time?
The old way I did is call it for multiple times. When I captured a picture, immediately send it to server.
Also search and watch video but have no clue,
because of some reason that I don't want to send FTP request.

Comment: Oh. When I look up again, I realize that i put 2 row :
 request.headers.addAll(header);
        updateImage(request);
In the loop so it wrong. Then I move it after I add all files I needed, it work! Thanks for that sir